# Foreign key to multiple tables via forwarding table

Tags: postgresql, database-design, referential-integrity

### Problem statement

I have a table with a column whose values are foreign keys, but the
target table of the foreign key differs from row to row. The relevant
table can be determined from the key value alone, and there is a small,
fixed set of such tables.

I'd like to add a foreign key constraint here so that my DBMS can ensure
referential integrity. Of course, I can't do this directly, but I have a
proposed solution that involves an intermediate "forwarding table" with
incoming and outgoing foreign key constraints. I'm looking for review
on:

- whether this solution in fact solves the problem, or if I missed an
  edge case;
- how this solution may fare in the face of changes to the data model
  (e.g., new referent tables);
- whether this use of Postgres `GENERATED ALWAYS AS ... STORED`
  columns is reasonable or suspect;
- whether this solution is likely to introduce concurrency issues.

### Proposed solution

To illustrate the solution, consider a simple database that stores
"users" and "groups". Users and groups are each keyed by integer IDs,
and some bits of the ID are reserved to tell what kind of ID it is:

```sql
-- User and group IDs are both integers, but are in disjoint subsets of the key
-- space, distinguished by the low 8 bits.
CREATE DOMAIN userid AS int8 CHECK ((VALUE & 255) = 1);
CREATE DOMAIN groupid AS int8 CHECK ((VALUE & 255) = 2);

CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id userid PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE groups(
    group_id groupid PRIMARY KEY,
    admin userid NOT NULL REFERENCES users
);

INSERT INTO users(user_id, name) VALUES (1, 'alice'), (257, 'bob');
INSERT INTO groups(group_id, admin) VALUES (2, 1), (258, 1);
```

Now, both users and groups can create invoices. Invoices have entirely
the same data whether they're created by a user or a group, so we just
use a single table that stores the ID of the "actor" (user or group)
that created the invoice along with the extra data:

```sql
-- Invoices can be created by either users or groups: collectively, "actors".
CREATE DOMAIN actorid AS int8 CHECK ((VALUE & 255) IN (1, 2));
CREATE TABLE invoices(
    actor actorid NOT NULL,
    create_time timestamptz NOT NULL,
    amount_cents int NOT NULL
);
```

Now, semantically, `invoices.actor` is a foreign key onto *either*
`users` or `groups`, depending on the value of `actor & 255`. There's no
way to directly write a `REFERENCES` constraint for that. We can imagine
defining a view of all the actor IDs—

```sql
CREATE VIEW all_actor_ids AS (
    SELECT user_id AS actor FROM users
    UNION ALL
    SELECT group_id AS actor FROM groups
);
```

—such that, in principle, `actor actorid REFERENCES all_actor_ids`, but
[Postgres does not actually allow referring to views in foreign
keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499323/is-it-possible-to-refer-a-column-in-a-view-as-foreign-key-postgresql-9-4).

To work around this, we basically materialize `all_actor_ids` into a
table that itself has foreign key constraints to ensure its own
integrity:

```sql
CREATE TABLE actors(
    actor actorid PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id userid
        REFERENCES users
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN (actor & 255) = 1 THEN actor END) STORED,
    group_id groupid
        REFERENCES groups
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN (actor & 255) = 2 THEN actor END) STORED,
    CONSTRAINT actors_exactly_one_key
        CHECK (1 = (user_id IS NOT NULL)::int + (group_id IS NOT NULL)::int)
);
```

Now, `invoices.actor` can refer to `actors`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE invoices ADD FOREIGN KEY (actor) REFERENCES actors;
```

The idea is that, before you add an invoice on behalf of an actor, you
first run `INSERT INTO actors(actor) VALUES($1) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`.
The generated columns take care of populating either `user_id` xor
`group_id`, the foreign key constraints on those columns ensure that the
underlying entity actually exists, and the conflict handler makes the
operation a no-op if the actor has been used before.

For example, with the above definitions, these inserts work:

```sql
-- All users and groups can be populated as actors.
INSERT INTO actors(actor)
    SELECT user_id FROM users UNION ALL SELECT group_id FROM groups
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

-- Invoices can be created for either actors or groups.
INSERT INTO invoices(actor, create_time, amount_cents)
    VALUES (1, now(), 100), (258, now(), 200);
```

Note that the `actors` data never actually needs to be part of a `JOIN`
in a read path. It exists only to coax the foreign key constraints into
submission.

### Questions

It seems to me that this solution should properly ensure referential
integrity: in particular, a user or group can't be deleted without
cascading down to delete any invoices created by that user or group.
But I have some questions:

- Am I missing some edge case in which this solution does not actually
  ensure referential integrity?
- Suppose that invoices can now also be created by a third type of
  entity: say, `robots`. I think that I can alter the `actorid` domain
  to incorporate `robotid`s, then add a new `actors.robot_id` column
  like the others and update the `actors_exactly_one_key` constraint.
  Are there lurking issues that I should be wary of here?
- I haven't used Postgres `GENERATED ALWAYS AS ... STORED` columns
  before, and I'm a little nervous that the default expression can't
  be changed at all after the fact. Does this seem like an appropriate
  use of generated columns, or would it be better to replace the
  generated columns with `CHECK` constraints that ensure the same
  values but require the user to provide them?
- Is the `INSERT INTO actors(actor) ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` likely
  to introduce concurrency issues? (Or, are there any other glaring
  performance issues that I've missed?)

Any other feedback or reviews also warmly appreciated.

I'm using Postgres 12, but if the best solution here requires upgrading
to Postgres 14, I'm open to it.

Comment: This is a notoriously difficult problem, and there are several approaches. I see no flaw with your idea.

Comment: Something reminded me of Rube Goldberg.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you overcomplicating yourself?

Much simpler:

Make 1 column for each possible FK, then add a CHECK constraint to make sure that only 1 column is not-NULL and the rest stay NULL (if you want only 1 FK, you may want more).

Also much simpler:

Add FKs to the *other* tables, the *other* tables will all have an FK to the same *main* table, this way the DB has no constraint on how many relationships there may be but this might be simple to do through application logic and comes with the benefit of a very robust-looking DB schema. (if your requirements about *how many relationships there may be to the main table* changes, you don't even have to run a migration).

Personally I prefer to avoid anything with the word *materialize* if possible.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with Jose that you are overcomplicating the problem.
I think you can write a simple trigger on the column you want the database to check its integrity.
I mean something like

```
select ((select * from users where user_id = actor_id) or (select * from "groups" where group_id = actor_id))
```

Comment: _Currently, `CHECK` expressions cannot contain subqueries nor refer to variables other than columns of the current row._

Comment: You are right, I should have said a trigger to check. I'll correct it.